# video tag src not picking ftp url as a source?

Tags: html, video

in video tag src we are trying to give src as a ftp resource its not picking it up. Can somebody give some direction on that.

`<video src='ftp://server/pqr.mp4' />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: the src actually points to a ftp:// location and is not playing thats what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that's because to allow efficient usage, the browser makes HTTP range requests, which are part of HTTP, not FTP. FTP is a pretty old protocol, and isn't really appropriate here for lots of reasons (no range requests, basic/no caching info, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is :

Loading an FTP sub-resource through an HTTP / S page is not allowed

This is for security issues, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361848

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="http://movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a seven year old question with three other existing answers it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses and to note if the passage of time and changes in HTML have impacted the answer. It also appears that you didn't close the video tag making this answer confusing. Please edit the answer to include an explanation.