# Embed video in html using ftp url

Tags: android, html, video, ftp

I need to embed in html a video file from a local nas that can only be access using ftp. The html file is actually part of a intranet site that needs to be accessed from android devices...
The problem is that I am not able to do that using video tag (It works ok using Chrome on desktop but not on android device...)(same problem as [video tag src not picking ftp url as a source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677266/video-tag-src-not-picking-ftp-url-as-a-source)) (though it works ok for images...)

Can you please advise me how to do this/ direct me to video embeding controls that can do this on android?
Thank you :-)

P.S.

I have tried like this:

```
<img src="ftp://username:pass@mynasip/stihl-logo.jpg">
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="ftp://username:pass@mynasip/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="ftp://username:pass@mynasip/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

the image works ok for desktop & android device
 the video works if using chrome desktop browser but does not work for android...

Comment: ftp does not support access to specific parts of the file like http does with range requests, e.g. a video player would only be able to support pause or continue or forward if the whole file was downloaded already to local disk. So even if you would be able to embed it it would not be much fun to use.

Comment: ftp supports REST command so it should be possible (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html)

Comment: You are right, but it does not support a range-like command. E.g. the only way to retrieve bytes 100..200 is to issue a REST 100 and then close the data connection after receiving 100 bytes and hoping that the server does not complain about it - there is no way to order the server to just give you 100 bytes.

Comment: @bogdanbrudiu So at last, you found any solution to play video over ftp in Android, I have same situation as you like I am also trying to play video from NAS device to Android app?